# Why and how does this finding the auction winner query work?

Tags: mysql, sql, join, greatest-n-per-group

A friend of mine came up with the following query for finding the winning bets

```
SELECT b1.*
FROM bids as b1
LEFT JOIN bids AS b2 ON b1.item_id = b2.item_id AND b1.bid_price < b2.bid_price
WHERE b2.item_id IS NULL
```

It appears to be working correctly, but I don't understand how it works and whether it's by accident or the result will be always the same. Can someone please explain, how it works, and especially how does `b1.bid_price < b2.bid_price` work with apparently non-existent b2.bid_price?

Here's the dump:

```
CREATE TABLE `bids` (
  `bid_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `bid_price` decimal(10,2) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `user_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `item_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `bid_date_created` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp(),
  PRIMARY KEY (`bid_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=18 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4

INSERT INTO bids VALUES (1, 14000.33, 12, 1, '2021-10-27 19:07:21');
INSERT INTO bids VALUES (2, 13000.60, 6, 1, '2021-10-27 18:07:21');
INSERT INTO bids VALUES (3, 21000.00, 7, 4, '2021-10-29 18:07:21');
INSERT INTO bids VALUES (4, 17000.25, 6, 4, '2021-10-27 18:07:21');
INSERT INTO bids VALUES (6, 5500.00, 6, 7, '2021-11-21 11:46:17');
INSERT INTO bids VALUES (7, 1000.00, 6, 29, '2021-11-22 11:21:41');
INSERT INTO bids VALUES (8, 18000.00, 6, 1, '2021-11-23 11:21:11');
INSERT INTO bids VALUES (9, 110.00, 14, 30, '2021-11-28 15:24:56');
INSERT INTO bids VALUES (10, 120.00, 13, 30, '2021-11-28 15:25:11');
INSERT INTO bids VALUES (11, 159.00, 14, 30, '2021-11-28 15:25:19');
INSERT INTO bids VALUES (12, 170.00, 13, 30, '2021-11-28 15:25:34');
INSERT INTO bids VALUES (13, 200.00, 14, 30, '2021-11-28 15:25:57');
INSERT INTO bids VALUES (14, 250.00, 13, 30, '2021-11-28 15:26:02');
INSERT INTO bids VALUES (15, 6000.00, 14, 6, '2021-11-28 15:26:30');
INSERT INTO bids VALUES (16, 7300.00, 13, 6, '2021-11-28 15:26:44');
INSERT INTO bids VALUES (17, 10000.00, 14, 6, '2021-11-28 15:29:14');
```

Comment: it finds `b1` such that there is not any `b2` with higher price, so `b1` is with highest price.

Comment: When no `b1.bid_price < b2.bid_price` exists every `b2` column is `null` due to `left join`. Testing not nullable column of the underlying table being `null` detects the case.

Comment: [Is there any rule of thumb to construct SQL query from a human-readable description?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33952141/3404097)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query uses LEFT OUTER JOIN to *try* to find a row `b2` that matches the same `item_id` as `b1`, but a greater `bid_price` than the value in `b1`.

The way left outer joins work is that if there is no match, then the columns from the left table (`b1`) are returned anyway, and the columns of `b2` are NULL. You can see that in your example data if we test the query without its WHERE clause.

```
mysql> SELECT b1.bid_id, b1.item_id, b2.bid_id, b2.item_id 
FROM bids as b1 LEFT JOIN bids AS b2 ON b1.item_id = b2.item_id 
  AND b1.bid_price < b2.bid_price;
+--------+---------+--------+---------+
| bid_id | item_id | bid_id | item_id |
+--------+---------+--------+---------+
|      2 |       1 |      1 |       1 |
|      4 |       4 |      3 |       4 |
|      1 |       1 |      8 |       1 |
|      2 |       1 |      8 |       1 |
|      9 |      30 |     10 |      30 |
|      9 |      30 |     11 |      30 |
|     10 |      30 |     11 |      30 |
|      9 |      30 |     12 |      30 |
|     10 |      30 |     12 |      30 |
|     11 |      30 |     12 |      30 |
|      9 |      30 |     13 |      30 |
|     10 |      30 |     13 |      30 |
|     11 |      30 |     13 |      30 |
|     12 |      30 |     13 |      30 |
|      9 |      30 |     14 |      30 |
|     10 |      30 |     14 |      30 |
|     11 |      30 |     14 |      30 |
|     12 |      30 |     14 |      30 |
|     13 |      30 |     14 |      30 |
|     15 |       6 |     16 |       6 |
|     15 |       6 |     17 |       6 |
|     16 |       6 |     17 |       6 |
|      3 |       4 |   NULL |    NULL |
|      6 |       7 |   NULL |    NULL |
|      7 |      29 |   NULL |    NULL |
|      8 |       1 |   NULL |    NULL |
|     14 |      30 |   NULL |    NULL |
|     17 |       6 |   NULL |    NULL |
+--------+---------+--------+---------+
```

Most of the rows match `b1` to some row `b2` with the same `item_id` but a greater `bid_price`.

In the last six rows, the bid `b1` has no other bid with a greater `bid_price`, so those six are the ones that are greatest for each `item_id`. Those are the ones you want in the result.

An easy way of filtering for those is with the WHERE clause you saw:

```
WHERE b2.item_id IS NULL
```

Really, you could use any column from `b2` that is known to be non-NULL, because that means the only way it would be NULL is that there was no match because of the LEFT OUTER JOIN.

Comment: Thank you very much! Like it usually happens, after posting the question I managed to remove the where clause myself and beheld this progression of bets compared to each other. And then with your "if there is no match, then... b2 are NULL" it clicked. And also I believe it explains why this query is 5x slower than using a subquery in WHERE - just because of so many rows returned/examined by this join.

Comment: The performance depends on the number of items and number of matched rows. In some cases, using the left outer join method is much faster than using correlated subqueries. See also my answer to https://stackoverflow.com/a/1313293/20860

Comment: Usually yes, but in this case a query `SELECT b.* FROM items i JOIN bids b ON i.item_id = b.item_id and b.bid_price = (SELECT MAX(b1.bid_price) FROM bids b1 WHERE b1.item_id = i.item_id)` performs 3x-5x faster than the query above. I am yet to find why. But it seems that explain format="json" supports my claim. not only the query cost is like 10x less with subquery but also for the join it says "rows_produced_per_join": 2138128 (on a table with 100k lots)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a quick breakdown of what's happening:

Let's start with the join itself. `LEFT JOIN` indicates that it will get all results from the left side (b1) and any corresponding results from the right side (b2) if they exist. If not, all the columns in b2 will be null (keep this in mind as it plays a huge part in how this query works).

Next, it joins on `item_id`, so it only gets the prices for that specific item. Then, it has another join condition, `b1.bid_price < b2.bid_price`. Any comparison with `NULL` will ultimately be evaluated as false. Keep in mind that both of these conditions have to be met or else all the rows in `b2`  are null, and also that `b2` is representing each entry in the `bets` table. This means that if `b2` is null, it's either the only bet for that item (because of the `b1.item_id = b2.item_id` constraint), or it's the highest (because of the `b1.bid_price < b2.bid_price` constraint).

Lastly, the `WHERE` clause. As mentioned above, the `JOIN` clause is set up perfectly so that the highest bids will all have `NULL` values in `b2`. That makes this part easy, because now the `WHERE` clause can simply get every instance where the joined `b2` has `NULL` values.